# How to get user name and respective group membership in active directory with powershell

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I want to get the list of users and respective group membership by powershell.

like:

```
Name    GroupName
user1     group1
user1     group2
user2     group3
```

I creted a script like this

```
get-aduser -filter * -properties memberof | %{select $._Name, @{Name='GroupName' ; Expression={get-adprincipalgroupmembership $._distinguisedName | Select Name }}}
```

but not getting any output.

Any help will be appriciated.

Comment: Your syntax is not correct (e.g., `$._` should be `$_.` and your ussage of Foreach-Object e.g. `% { ... }` is not needed.  There are many resources on the internet with examples that you should probably read before just coming here and posting your first attempt at scripting

Answer (score 1):

The syntax used for your [calculated property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_calculated_properties?view=powershell-7.2) on [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-7.2#example-11--create-calculated-properties-for-each-inputobject) is incorrect as [Daniel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11954025/daniel) pointed out in his helpful comment, in addition, [`foreach` loop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_foreach?view=powershell-7.2) is also better in this case:

```
foreach($user in Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties MemberOf) {
    Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $user |
        Select-Object @{N='User'; E={ $user.Name }}, @{N='GroupName'; E='Name'}
}
```